# Can CSS table layout handle missing cells?

Tags: html, css, tablelayout

I've reproduced an Excel spreadsheet in HTML with lots of DIVs, a reasonable amount of CSS, and a sprinkling of JavaScript.

Great - there are frozen rows when scrolling vertically, and frozen columns when scrolling horizontally, **but I have to use an empty DIV wherever there's an empty cell** or I lose my gridlines.  **So I currently have over 180,000 DIVs (mostly empty)** consuming 2GB of RAM, whereas Excel displays the same spreadsheet in 5MB!

Do CSS' table-layout tags offer a more efficient way to handle sparse data?  Useful documentation on them is just as sparse.

Comment: Instead of using `<table>`s, you can just use [CSS grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) and style your `<div>`s to position them explicitly in a certain row or column. This will almost certainly be more memory efficient. You can also consider using virtualized scrolling - that is, loading the elements when the user tries to scroll to them, instead of keeping everything in memory at once.

Comment: Why would you need to put all the data on one page?

Comment: No.  `table-layout` is just a mechanism for allowing table-like layout in non-table DOM elements.   180,000 DOM elements will have poor performance regardless of your layout style; I think you're either going to need to paginate the display, or cull the empty elements before trying to represent them in the DOM.

Comment: @aris: Because I can ctrl-left and right to find things hundreds of times faster than writing even a simple SQL query.  Realizing that, I'm thinking it's best to let Excel do what it excels at.  If I just finish my MySQL library, I can export a new spreadsheet from the source-of-truth whenever it's needed.